React Native Layout error after creating new project without framwork
node_modules@react-native/gradle-plugin/settings-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/ReactSettingsExtension.kt:26:Unresolved reference: layout
After creating new project in React Native without framework using https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.75/getting-started-without-a-framework   this link getting layout error, gradle version https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-all.zip
